# How to use wget with GET parameter, or redirect web?

Tags: cron, wget

sorry,.. I'm noob in Ubuntu ... and I'm trying to make a robots for downloading file..

i can download the zip file via web browser's address bar like this

`http://www.mysite.com/getFile.php?mirror=1&categori=advanture&file=001.zip`

but, when i try to use `wget`, the file never been downloaded...

this is how i use wget :

```
$ wget -H http://www.mysite.com/getFile.php?mirror=1&categori=images&file=001.zip
$ wget -H -k http://www.mysite.com/getFile.php?mirror=1&categori=images&file=001.zip
$ wget -H -m http://www.mysite.com/getFile.php?mirror=1&categori=images&file=001.zip
$ wget -H -m -k http://www.mysite.com/getFile.php?mirror=1&categori=images&file=001.zip
```

all wget just download the php file.. when i open it, it's just
`<font color=red>invalid url</font>`

does it because of redirect ? or cookie ? when i clear all cookie in mozilla, and download again.. it still wokrs..

or session ? mysite.com is never use login user to download

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use apostrophes or double quotes around the URL, because it contains the special character `&`.

Comment: thanks.... i dont know that `&` is spesial char

Answer (score 7):

You have to use single(`'`) or double quotes(`"`) in URL, so the link should look like this:

```
$ wget "http://www.mysite.com/getFile.php?mirror=1&categori=images&file=001.zip"
```

Comment: sorry,.. i accept @elmicha answer.. cause he answer first.. but thanks,... i vot up your answer..

Answer (score -1):

Really awesome solution....!
It works for me perfectly.

Thanks....

```
$command = "wget 'URL WITH QUERY STRING'";

exec("$command >/dev/null &");
```